# Rails Active Record equivalent of SQL with conditional expressions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following `SQL`

```
SELECT a,
       CASE WHEN a=1 THEN 'one'
            WHEN a=2 THEN 'two'
            ELSE 'other'
       END
    FROM test;
```

With active record I tried building the query like

```
  @tests =  Test.find_by_sql(
           "SELECT a,
               CASE WHEN a=1 THEN 'one'
                    WHEN a=2 THEN 'two'
                    ELSE 'other'
               END
            FROM test")
```

But not returning the desired resultset!

> `[#<Test a: 1>, #<Test a: 2>, #<Test  a: 3>, ......]`

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Not working in what way, error, not the desired output?

Comment: @Iceman not the desired output it still returns 1,2....

Comment: That is to be expected, you're selecting the column `a` from the db, but the `case...when` is returning the result in a different column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing this in AR so you will have to write in the `case..when` part, but at least this is much closer to the Rails way.

```
tests = Test.all.select(%(
  a, 
  (CASE WHEN a=1 THEN 'one'
                WHEN a=2 THEN 'two'
                ELSE 'other' END) as a_text
))

tests.first.a_text #= 'one' or 'two'
```